# Environment Path - Terminal OSX

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I can run a java -classpath command without issue directly in terminal but as soon as I try to do it in cron it throws this error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available (implies -server, only for x86_64)
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -jvm          is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output`
```

Research has told me that this might be an environment path issue? How do I tell what my path is when using terminal vs cron?

I'm envoking java right from cron, crontab is something like:

0 3 * * * * java -classpath /Users/tb582/Desktop/sample1.jar:/Users/tb582......

Comment: Are you invoking `java` from a script or directly from cron? Would you post the the script (or the cron invocation)?

Answer (score 0):

just specify the whole path in cron:

type "which java"

should output something similar to this:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: I doubt this will fix the problem. It's apparent from the output in the OP (java usage) that cron is finding a `java` binary just fine.

Comment: added onto cron `/usr/bin/java` so now its `30 20 * * * * /usr/bin/java java -classpath` .... getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)`

Comment: You should be using /usr/bin/java -classpath (you have a second 'java') in there